# How to get field names from Opencart2 Mysqli Query

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart2.x

Im trying to get the field names In opencart from a dynamic Mysqli Query but im getting the following error:-

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_fields() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in [mypath]
```

This is when an SELECT query that returns rows is run

the queries run so its not because the query is failing or returning a null result.

This is a code example

```
$mysqlQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM attribute");
        $fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_fields($mysqlQuery);
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I assume you have `'DB_DRIVER'=> 'mysqli'` in your config file.

Now When you run `$mysqlQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."attribute");`

The `db` which executes `mySqli->query` function to fetch data so lets add `fetch_fields()` function to `mySqli->query` return value

```
system/library/db/mysqli.php:32
```

After `$result->rows = $data;`

Add `$result->fields = $query->fetch_fields();`

Now you can get Fields by calling

```
$mysqlQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."attribute");
print_r($mysqlQuery->fields);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but wouldn't this add overhead to the whole site? when its only needed in one query call in a particular module?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`$columns = $this->db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "table_name");
print_r($columns->rows);`

Answer (score 0):

In the end i just used the Associative Array of query results and used a foreach loop with as $key to output the table head names.

```
<?php foreach($results as $key => $result); ?>
```

This works very well for my needs.